# Translate of https request from java to delphi

Tags: java, delphi, idhttp

Have the following java code:

```
    // Set your API key: remember to change this to your live API key in production
    String apiKeyUserName = "your api username";
    String apiKeyPassword = "your api password";

    // Set the query params
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fromPostcode", "2000"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("toPostcode", "3000"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("networkId", "01"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lodgementDate", "2013-08-01"));
    String query = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF-8");

    String urlPrefix = "api.auspost.com.au";
    String validateURL = "https://" + urlPrefix + "/DeliveryDates.xml?";

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(validateURL + query);
    httpGet.addHeader("Cookie", "OBBasicAuth=fromDialog");
    httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(apiKeyUserName, apiKeyPassword),
        "US-ASCII",false));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
```

Want to translate this into an Delphi. For the request I used TIdHttp as below:

```
procedure RequestDeliveryDate;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  lResponse: String;
  requestURL: String;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create();
  IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
  IdHTTP.Request.Username := 'your api username';
  IdHTTP.Request.Password := 'your api password';
  IdHTTP.Request.CharSet := 'utf-8';

  LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create();
  IdHTTP.IOHandler := LHandler;

  requestURL := 'https://api.auspost.com.au/DeliveryDates.xml?fromPostcode=2000' +
                                                            '&toPostcode=3000' +
                                                            '&networkId=01' +
                                                            '&lodgementDate=2018-02-23' +
                                                            '&numberOfDates=01';
  screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  try
    lResponse := IdHTTP.Get(requestURL);
    screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      screen.Cursor := crDefault;
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  end;
  IdHTTP.Free;
end;
```

Let's presume that I do supply the right api user name and password. When I call the above code I get the following error:
"This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested.
Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required."

What I'm doing wrong? Any suggestion?

Comment: You're missing the `Cookie`.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to add it? Wasn't able to implement it ... 2-3 lines of code would be appreciated.

Comment: added the following code to the request:
IdHTTP.CookieManager := TIdCookieManager.Create(IdHTTP);
URI := TIdURI.Create(requestURL);
IdHTTP.CookieManager.AddServerCookie('OBBasicAuth=fromDialog', URI);
URI.Free;

... but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: The log of the request looks like this:
Sent 2/25/2018 7:47:18 PM: GET /DeliveryDates.xml?fromPostcode=2100&toPostcode=2001&networkId=01&lodgementDate=2018-02-25&numberOfDates=01 HTTP/1.1<EOL>
Host: api.auspost.com.au<EOL>
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<EOL>Accept-Encoding: identity<EOL>
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)<EOL>
Authorization: Basic ODEzNmM2NTktOTY2OC00ZTM3LWFjMzItODkwMWJjNThlM2ZhOlN1Y2Nlc3MwMSE=<EOL>
Cookie: OBBasicAuth=fromDialog<EOL><EOL>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ElliottFrisch stated in comments, you are not sending the `Cookie` header. There are two ways to do that:

- use the `CustomHeaders` property:

  ```
  IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Cookie', 'OBBasicAuth=fromDialog');
  ```
- use the `CookieManager` property to fake an actual cookie and let `TIdHTTP` generate the `Cookie` header for you (be sure to assign a `TIdCookieManager` component beforehand, and set `TIdHTTP. AllowCookies=True`):

  ```
  url := TIdURI.Create('https://api.auspost.com.au/DeliveryDates.xml');
  try
    IdHTTP.CookieManager.AddServerCookie('OBBasicAuth=fromDialog', url);
  finally
    url.Free;
  end;
  ```

You are also leaking the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` object. I suggest assigning the `TIdHTTP` as its `Owner`. And the call to `IdHTTP.Free` should be in a `try..finally` for good measure.

Try this:

```
procedure RequestDeliveryDate;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  requestURL, query, lResponse: String;
  //url: TIdURI;
begin
  requestURL := 'https://api.auspost.com.au/DeliveryDates.xml';
  query := '?fromPostcode=2000' +
           '&toPostcode=3000' +
           '&networkId=01' +
           '&lodgementDate=2018-02-23' +
           '&numberOfDates=01';

  try
    IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
    try
      IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
      IdHTTP.Request.Username := 'your api username';
      IdHTTP.Request.Password := 'your api password';

      IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Cookie', 'OBBasicAuth=fromDialog');    
      {
      url := TIdURI.Create(requestURL);
      try
        IdHTTP.CookieManager.AddServerCookie('OBBasicAuth=fromDialog', url);
      finally
        url.Free;
      end;
      }

      LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
      IdHTTP.IOHandler := LHandler;

      screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
      try
        lResponse := IdHTTP.Get(requestURL + query);
      finally
        screen.Cursor := crDefault;
      end;
    finally
      IdHTTP.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's working with the CookieManager: It appears that I also found the solution but for some reasons, I do not understand, I have to add '@auspost.com.au' to the provided API Key ...